# Editar com Radio button em jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2, java-8

Bom estou comecando agora a desenvolver com o JSF e estou com uma duvida de como fazer para o meu metodo editar receba o objeto certo do radio button , do jeito que esta implementado ele sempre pega o primeiro da table e nao o que esta selecionado pelo radio, o que eu deixei de ver ?

> JSF

```
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{resource['css:materialize.min.css']}" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="#{resource['css:style.css']}" type="text/css"/>
    <title>Usuários</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

</h:head>
<style>
    .fixed-action-btn.horizontal ul {
        top: 47%;
    }

</style>
<h:body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{resource['js:jquery-3.2.1.min.js']}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{resource['js:materialize.min.js']}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{resource['js:scripts.js']}"/>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-wrapper indigo lighten-1">
            <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['imagens:logo_white.png']}" class="brand-logo center"/>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left">
                <li>  <a id="menu" href="#">
                        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                    </a>   
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-small-only">


                <li>  <a id="menu" href="#">Settings</a>   
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>


    <h:messages />
    <div class="divDados  grey lighten-4">

        <div class="divCima indigo lighten-2">

            <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal click-to-toggle right ">
                <a class="btn-floating  indigo lighten-1 z-depth-3">
                    <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="btn-floating purple darken-4 z-depth-3"  href="../index.jsf"><i class="material-icons">home</i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn-floating red darken-1 z-depth-3"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a></li>
                    <li><h:form>
                            <h:commandLink id="menu" styleClass="btn-floating yellow darken-1 z-depth-3" action="#{BeanUsers.editar()}">
                                <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{BeanUsers.selectedItem}"
                                                             value="#{usuario}" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </h:form></li>
                    <li><h:form>
                            <h:commandLink id="menu" styleClass="btn-floating green darken-1 z-depth-3" action="#{BeanUsers.cadastrar}">
                                <i class="material-icons">add</i>
                            </h:commandLink>
                        </h:form></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <h4 class="white-text" style="text-align: center">Usuários</h4>
        </div>
        <div class=" dadosListar container"> 

            <h:form>

                <h:dataTable binding="#{BeanUsers.dataTable}" value="#{BeanUsers.listar()}" var="usuario" rules="row" cellpadding="5" styleClass="bordered striped" >
                    <f:facet name="header">Selecionar</f:facet>

                    <h:column>
                        <h:selectOneRadio value="#{BeanUsers.usuario}"  valueChangeListener="#{BeanUsers.setSelectedItem}" onclick="selectOneRadio(this)">
                            <f:selectItem    itemValue="#{usuario}"  />
                        </h:selectOneRadio>
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>

                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Ativo</f:facet>
                            #{usuario.ativo}

                    </h:column> 
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Nome</f:facet>
                            #{usuario.nome}
                    </h:column> 
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Cargo</f:facet>
                            #{usuario.office}
                    </h:column> 

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">Telefone</f:facet>
                            #{usuario.celular}
                    </h:column> 

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">E-mail</f:facet>
                            #{usuario.email}
                    </h:column> 

                </h:dataTable>

            </h:form>
        </div>
        #{usuario.id}
        <div class="divBaixo indigo lighten-2"></div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

> BEAN

```
@ManagedBean(name = "BeanUsers")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanUsers {

    private Users usuario = new Users();
    private String confirmarSenha;
    private List<Users> lista;
    private HtmlDataTable dataTable;

    public List<Users> listar() {
        if (this.lista == null) {
            UsersBO usersBO = new UsersBO();
            this.lista = usersBO.listar();
        }

        return this.lista;
    }

    public String users() {

        return "/publico/users";
    }

    public String cadastrar() {
        this.usuario = new Users();
        this.usuario.setAtivo(true);
        return "/publico/cadUsers";
    }

    public String salvar() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        String senha = this.usuario.getSenha();
        if (!senha.equals(this.confirmarSenha)) {
            FacesMessage facesMessage = new FacesMessage("A senha nao foi confirmada corretamente");
            context.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
            return null;
        }

        UsersBO usersBO = new UsersBO();
        usersBO.salvar(this.usuario);

        return "/publico/users";
    }

    public Users getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Users usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getConfirmarSenha() {
        return confirmarSenha;
    }

    public void setConfirmarSenha(String confirmarSenha) {
        this.confirmarSenha = confirmarSenha;
    }

    public String editar() {

       this.usuario = usuario.getSelectedItem();
        this.confirmarSenha = this.usuario.getSenha();

        return "/publico/cadUsers";
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {

        usuario = (Users) dataTable.getRowData();

    }

    public void getSelectedItem() {

        ArrayList<Users> selectedDataList = new ArrayList<Users>();
        selectedDataList.add(usuario);


    }

    ;



         public HtmlDataTable getDataTable() {
        return dataTable;
    }

    public void setDataTable(HtmlDataTable dataTable) {
        this.dataTable = dataTable;
    }
}
```

> JS

```
function selectOneRadio(radio) {
var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
var el = radio.form.elements;
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
        el[i].checked = false;
    }
}
radio.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Não entendi a parte do JS. Se é radio button, todos deveriam ter o mesmo nome e apenas 1 deveria estar selecionado. Pra que serve então essa função `selectOneRadio(radio)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um detalhe importante no seu DataTable e no selectOneRadio, é que da forma que foi codificado, será gerado um radio para cada linha da tabela, assim sendo, isto não impede que o usuário selecione mais de um registro, mas parece que a sua função javascript selectOneRadio tem o objetivo de "corrigir" esta situação, mas isto ficou meio que, me perdoe a expressão, uma gambiarra danada.

Talvez fosse melhor reavaliar esta abordagem, não sei quais as tecnologias usadas em seu projeto, mas o PrimeFaces possui um DataTable com seleção radio, que serviria como uma luva para o seu caso, você pode ver o exemplo [aqui](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/selection.xhtml).

Um problema grave gerado por essa abordagem, é que o selectOneRadio esta linkado com o atributo usuario de seu Bean, mas como mencionado acima, para cada linha da tabela será gerado um radio, e no fim todos os radios gerados estão linkados ao mesmo atributo usuario de seu Bean, consegue ver o problema? Por exemplo, vamos supor que em seu Bean exista um atributo **String chamado teste**, e que você linkou este atributo a dois inputText na mesma página, **qual dos valores preenchidos pelo usuário (o valor do primeiro ou do segundo inputText) que será repassado para o atributo teste no back end(Bean)**?? Percebeu que os valores que você vai receber no back end podem apresentar um comportamento inesperado?

Mas supondo que você não queira ou não possa usar PrimeFaces, e não deseja mudar a abordagem, eu sugiro usar ajax de forma explícita, e passar a o valor do var do dataTable para o listener do ajax, o porém dessa abordagem, é a necessidade de um conversor, e ainda temos a situação discutida no parágrafo anterior para ser resolvida, mas seguindo em frente, seria algo mais ou menos assim:

## Conversor

```
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    @FacesConverter(value = "ConversorUsers")
    @ManagedBean(eager = true)
    @ApplicationScoped
    public class ConversorUsers implements Converter {

        @Override
        public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
                return (Users) uic.getAttributes().get(value);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
            if (o instanceof Users) {
                Users entidade = (Users) o;
                if (entidade instanceof Users && entidade.getId() != null) {
                    uic.getAttributes().put(entidade.getId().toString(), entidade);
                   return entidade.getId().toString();
                }
            }
            return "";
        }    
    }
```

Para mais detalhes sobre conversores recomendo estes links:
[AlgaWorks](http://blog.algaworks.com/conversores-jsf/)
[MkYoung](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/)
[TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_customconvertor_tag.htm)

## XHTML

```
<h:column>
  <h:selectOneRadio value="#{BeanUsers.usuario}"  converter="ConversorUsers" onclick="selectOneRadio(this)">
    <f:selectItem    itemValue="#{usuario}"  />
    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{BeanUsers.setSelectedItem(usuario)}" />
  </h:selectOneRadio>
```

Foi adicionado o atributo converter no radio, com o nome especificado na anotação @FacesConverter da respectiva classe. No listener do ajax você pode passar a variável usuario(o var do dataTable) direto como argumento para o método setSelectedItem, e o atributo valuechangelistener do radio foi removido.

## Bean

Só estou postando as alterações.

```
private Users usuario = new Users();
 //adicionando um novo atributo usuarip
 private Users usuarioSelecionado = new Users();
//modificando o metodo para receber um Usuario
 public void setSelectedItem(Users u) {    
    usuarioSelecionado  = u;    
 }
```

Perceba que o atributo usuarioSelecionado não é referenciado no xhtml, assim garantimos que ele terá sempre o valor que for atribuído pelo método setSelectedItem, que por sua vez, obtém um usuario do radio/dataTabel. Se na página houvesse apenas um radio, você poderia linkar usuarioSelecionado direto com o value do selectOneRadio, mas como este último foi gerado várias vezes, usei essa abordagem para evitar o problema descrito no terceiro parágrafo.

Lembrando, (**sim eu sei que estou sendo repetitivo**) que seria extremamente recomendável rever a abordagem desta tela/página da sua aplicação, devido aos problemas citados anteriormente.

Comment: Ok, muito boa sua abordagem vou testar  a solucao que voce passou e ver se o primeFaces pode ser ultilizado na aplicacao sem maiores problemas.

Answer (score -1):

Exemplo funcional:

```
public void setSelectedItem(ValueChangeEvent event) {
     FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     selectedItem = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{usuario}", User.class);
}
```

Comment: a solucao apresentada não resolve.